# How do i remove the free shipping showing on my home page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

How do i remove the free shipping showing on the top of my home page.  I want to remove this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the file `app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/html/header.phtml` to your theme `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/html/header.phtml` and remove this:

```
<p class="top-promo" title="<?php echo $this->__('Free Shipping on orders over 50$'); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Free Shipping on orders over 50$'); ?></p>
```

Comment: Thanks.  It worked fine.  But i want to remove the now accepting Pay Pal and replace it with Pay on delivery.  Like wise i want to replace the Place where u have we are available24/7 with my details

Comment: you can enable the [template path hints](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints) see what template file contains what you want to change, copy it to your theme preserving the path and change what you need.